# How to split text in HTML and right-left align it?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table>

<tr>
  ...
  <td style="text-align:center;">
    abcdefghij abcdefgh<br>
    AB hello<br>
    XYZ hi
  </td>
  ...
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

It outputs the following:

```
abcdefghij abcdefgh
     AB hello
      XYZ hi
```

I would like it to output following:

```
abcdefghij abcdefgh
        AB hello
       XYZ hi
```

How do I go about doing that without modifying the rest of the table?
We can assume that the left and parts can be at most 10 characters each.
If it helps, the HTML is generated via JavaScript.

Comment: you can't just sort the text next to each other with "br." Why not create a container for each

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aligning text on a specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763127/aligning-text-on-a-specific-character)

Comment: Also related: [Can you align text by a symbol in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60663429/html-css-can-you-align-text-by-a-symbol-in-it#)

Comment: My question was answered at the link posted by @GarrettMotzner

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to align that without adding included to the posts alone. If there are any, I don't know. It would be more accurate to follow a path this way.

```css
tr td {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

tr td div {
  display: flex;
}

tr td div>span {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

tr td div>span:nth-of-type(2) {
  text-align: left;
}

tr td div>span:nth-of-type(1) {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    ...
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <div>
        <span> abcdefghij </span>
        <span>abcdefgh</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>AB </span>
        <span>hello</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>XYZ </span>
        <span>hi</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```